# Mautic CiviCRM Integration

Tags: integration, civicrm, mautic

Mautic supports few CRM [Integration](https://www.mautic.org/integrations/) (i.e., SugerCRM etc), but I am looking for CiviCRM integration. Unfortunately there is no integration as of now.
My questions are :

1. Is it possible to integrate CiviCRM and Moutic?
2. If yes, please guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, it's certainly possible with some development skills.
2. But to be more helpful, that's how I see. Mautic has Drupal integration (https://www.mautic.org/integrations/drupal/) . CiviCRM can be installed on top of Drupal (https://download.civicrm.org/civicrm-4.7.9-drupal.tar.gz?src=donate) . Drupal could be the glue between Mautic and CiviCRM. The further steps really depend on what do you expect from the integration, but my guidance is to write a Drupal module that connects the Drupal Mautic integration and CiviCRM's Drupal-facing part. If your needs are lightweight, it might be possible that it can be done only using the UI of Drupal by clicking around (skills needed nevertheless).

Comment: Can't use drupal. Thanks for your response, well I am working on CiviCRM API and Mautic API. Trying to just sync leads for now, if it works, will try to create a CiviCRM extension with it.